# q/kdb Selecting a variable in query

Tags: kdb

```
q)sym:`a`b`c
q)t:([] s:`g`v; p:2?10.)
```

Selecting the variable `sym` works fine in the following query :

```
q)select sym from t
```

However it throws an error while selecting with a table column, I am not able to figure out the reason

```
q)select sym, p from t
```

Comment: Although your question is one of curiosity, it should be noted that it is bad practice to select a global within an unrelated select from a table and to pass it off as if it's a column in that table. Very misleading and would be confusing to debug/maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `'length` error because the lists `sym` and `p` (column from `t`) are different lengths.

```
q)sym:`a`b
q)select sym,p from t
sym p
------------
a   3.927524
b   5.170911
```

What is the output you are trying to get to with this?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying combinations of select queries e.g. `select  p,sym:\`a from t`. Came across this one but I was not able to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to select as many elements of `sym` as the table count :

```
q)select p,(count i)#sym from t
p        sym
------------
1.780839 a
3.017723 b
```